# Difference between wild card SSL

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

I have deployed SSL certificates on various websites however this wildcard SSL certificate is totally new to me. I have question that If I am buying a SSL certificate `*.example-private.com`, Will it work for `*.staging.example-private.com` Or Do I have to buy a different wild card SSL for `staging` site. I am going to implement this on new sites.

Comment: This is NOT dupe of #436975; that Q is for wildcard **DNS** while this Q is for wildcard **SSL-cert** which are quite different things with _opposite_ answers (DNS wildcard is multilevel, cert isn't). OTOH #104160 #87869 #296390 #645230 _are_ dupes for wildcard SSL-cert.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A wildcard covers only one level. So `*.example.com` will cover `foo.example.com`, `bar.example.com`, and `staging.example.com` but **not** `foo.staging.example.com` or `example.com`.

However you can have multiple names (including wildcards) on the same certificate, so in principle a single certificate could be issued covering all the above names.

I know that CAs will happilly issue certificates covering both `example.com` and `*.example.com`, I'm not sure what typical policies are on issuing certificates with more names.

Also I would question whether this is really what you want. Do you really want to put your production secrets on your staging server?

Comment: Basically I am going to setup only my `*.example-private.com` site but I was not sure what to do.

Comment: I thought wildcard certificates by *default* covered the domain on it's own. That's at least how my certificates are issued.

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga That might be how yours are issued, but it's not how they work. The `*` does not match a non-existent label (technically, it matches exactly one label with any value), so to match both `example.com` and `*.example.com` the certificate needs to contain both of those two subject common names.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: must have both names yes, but in SAN as dNSName's not in Subject as CommonName's.

Answer (score 12):

A wildcard only matches one domain level, so `*.staging.example.com` would not be matched and you need another cert for subdomains of it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Peter and Sven, a wildcard will only support one wildcard level in the domain name.  This said, you have many possible ways to implement a naming scheme.

You can easily set up the servers in your production environment ( work.example.com ) and use the same certificate for your staging ( stagingwork.example.com ) and development ( devwork.example.com ) servers (those are separate from your production servers, correct?  :)  ).  One certificate, many hosts and domain names.

Answer (score 2):

Wildcard SSL Certificate can secure only first level sub-domains of the common name (CN), so when the certificate issued for *.example-private.com it can secure the root domain and it's all first level sub-domains as below.

```
staging.example-private.com
mail.example-private.com
anything.example-private.com
```

To secure second level sub-domains as *.staging.example-private.com, you have two options.

**1. Purchase another wildcard certificate:**

Your administrator needs to purchase the different certificates for each one and manage all  certificates configuration, renewal, expiry, and installation.

**2. Purchase Multi-Domain wildcard certificate:**

This product allows you to secure up to 100 websites and its unlimited sub-domains with a single certificate. You need to set *.example-private.com as your primary domain name and add another domain names in the SAN field.

For Example:

```
*.example-private.com
*.staging.example-private.com
*.anysub.example-private.com
*.anydomain.tld
```

For more information about how multi-domain wildcard certificate works, you can refer this link - https://www.ssl2buy.com/comodo-multi-domain-wildcard-ssl.php

Answer (score 0):

> A Wildcard SSL Certificate enables SSL encryption on multiple
>   subdomains using a single certificate. Subdomains on the certificate
>   must all share the same primary domain.

For instance, `example.com, www.example.com, blog.example.com,` could all be secured using the same wildcard SSL as they all use the same primary domain. However, `billing.yoursitesdomain.com` could not be used with this certificate, as it is using a different primary domain.

***one thing more***

**`LE supports "SAN"`** certificates where you need to specify every domain. There's no wildcards.
for more detail see this [LetsEncrypt Subdomain wildcard](https://discourse.roots.io/t/letsencrypt-subdomain-wildcard/7379)

**one thing more**

[this thread says](http://doghouse.agency/article/shared-wildcard-ssl-certificate-cpanelwhm) Ideally, our staging sites (*.our-agency-staging-domain.com) would all share the same self-signed SSL certificate. That would allow us to:

- Automatically make HTTPS available for all staging sites
- Avoid the cost and time overhead of purchasing 2 or 3 certs for each project
- Deliver a better experience to our developers

[another good link](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/set-up-cloudflare-free-ssl-on-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

You might have misinterpreted the function of Wildcard certificate. Wildcard SSL Certificate issued on *.example-private.com  will only secure single level, for example;

```
*.example-private.com will secure,

example-private.com
abc.example-private.com
def.example-private.com
ghi.example-private.com
```

Now if you want to secure second level sub-domains, you should go with Multi-Domain Wildcard certificate. This certificate will secure domains as under:

```
*example-private.com
www.example-private.com
shop.example-private.com
staging.example-private.com

*.staging.example-private.com
photos.staging.example-private.com
news.staging.example-private.com
blog.staging.example-private.com
```

I suggest you to browse [this article](https://www.cheapsslshop.com/blog/wildcard-ssl-bonding-of-lowest-cost-and-strong-security) to know more how Wildcard SSL can be helpful to secure sub-domains.