# Can't secure sub domain with SSL

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, ssl-certificate-errors

I am trying to secure a sub domain:

```
bitbucket.kl.company.com
```

The certificate is for *.company.com. So I get an error:

```
bitbucket.kl.company.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.company.com, company.com, bitbucket-mirror.company.com Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN
```

The puzzling thing is that some browsers don't complain, and load the page as expected. Is my certificate wrong? Can I order a certificate specifically for bitbucket.kl.company.com, and not use *.company.com?

Comment: Dupe https://serverfault.com/questions/104160/wildcard-ssl-certificate-for-second-level-subdomain and https://serverfault.com/questions/817255/difference-between-wild-card-ssl and several more. _All_ browsers should reject this at least once, although if the user approves an exception or override they may well work after that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a wildcard certificate and is valid only for third levels such as `name.company.com` and not fourth levels as the desired `bitbucket.kl.company.com`

You need to use another certificate for either the specific domain name or get a wildcard one for `*.kl.company.com`

Answer (score 1):

> The certificate is for *.company.com. So I get an error:

This is expected behaviour, as @whites11 already pointed out in [his answer](https://serverfault.com/a/871178/171476)

> The puzzling thing is that some browsers don't complain, and load the page as expected.

The problem here is: The implementation of wildcard certificate handling is pretty bad and especially quite inconsistent across browser vendors and versions. Don't expect them to work consistently on all platforms.

> Can I order a certificate specifically for bitbucket.kl.company.com, and not use *.company.com?

Yes you can. You just have to proof the ownership/control of `bitbucket.kl.company.com` to your favorite CA (e.g. Lets Encrypt) and they will issue said TLS certificate to you.